# Managing and testing PDFs with Karate

Tags: karate

I'd like to know whether Karate can read data from a PDF. Let me explain: I'm working on an invoicing application. Invoices are generated in PDF format.
I'd like to test whether the amount I enter in the app is identical to the one that appears on the generated PDF.

Thanks

Comment: karate has visual testing built in (relatively new) so see if that helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#compare-image - if you mean OCR, you may be able to re-use some code from karate-robot: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot